# Using distinct in a join

Tags: join, distinct

I'm still a novice at SQL and I need to run a report which JOINs 3 tables. The third table has duplicates of fields I need. So I tried to join with a distinct option but hat didn't work. Can anyone suggest the right code I could use?

## My Code looks like this:

```
SELECT 
   C.CUSTOMER_CODE
, MS.SALESMAN_NAME
, SUM(C.REVENUE_AMT)

FROM C_REVENUE_ANALYSIS C
JOIN M_CUSTOMER MC ON C.CUSTOMER_CODE = MC.CUSTOMER_CODE
/* This following JOIN is the issue. */
JOIN M_SALESMAN MS ON MC.SALESMAN_CODE = (SELECT SALESMAN_CODE FROM M_SALESMAN WHERE COMP_CODE = '00')

WHERE REVENUE_DATE >= :from_date 
  AND REVENUE_DATE <= :to_date

GROUP BY C.CUSTOMER_CODE, MS.SALESMAN_NAME
```

I also tried a different variation to get a DISTINCT.

```
/* I also tried this variation to get a distinct */

JOIN M_SALESMAN MS ON MC.SALESMAN_CODE = 
(SELECT distinct(SALESMAN_CODE) FROM M_SALESMAN)
```

Please can anyone help? I would truly appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As a head's up, there are many different databases that use SQL: SQL Server, MySQL, SQLite, Oracle, Sybase, etc... they all use a variation of SQL (Structured Query Language).  Try specifying which one you're using to get more detailed answers.  I've assumed you're using SQL Server for this question, currently.

Comment: My sincere apologies. This is a SQL Server database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select distinct
    c.customer_code,
    ms.salesman_code,
    SUM(c.revenue_amt)
FROM
    c_revenue c,
    m_customer mc,
    m_salesman ms
where
    c.customer_code = mc.customer_code
    AND mc.salesman_code = ms.salesman_code
    AND ms.comp_code = '00'
    AND Revenue_Date BETWEEN (from_date AND to_date)
group by
    c.customer_code, ms.salesman_name
```

The above will return you any distinct combination of Customer Code, Salesman Code and SUM of Revenue Amount where **the c.CustomerCode matches an mc.customer_code AND that same mc record matches an ms.salesman_code AND that ms record has a comp_code of '00' AND the Revenue_Date is between the from and to variables**.  Then, the whole result will be grouped by customer code and salesman name; the only thing that will cause duplicates to appear is if the SUM(revenue) is somehow different.

To explain, if you're just doing a straight JOIN, you don't need the JOIN keywords.  I find it tends to convolute things; you only need them if you're doing an "odd" join, like an LEFT/RIGHT join.  I don't know your data model so the above MIGHT still return duplicates but, if so, let me know.

Comment: I'm not sure why but that code doesn't work. Gives me a 'not a GROUP BY expression'.

Comment: Try removing the distinct; just realized that the GROUP BY should be taking care of the distinct by itself.  Otherwise, I'm not sure; that query should be good.  I'll run a quick test and get back to you.

Comment: I am so sorry. Your code works absolutely fine. I had erred in executing it.Thank you so much. I figured out the problem and fixed it.

Comment: Great!  I also just noticed that we were selecting ms.salesman_code but grouping on ms.salesman_name; my bad, I should have seen that.  Glad everything's working; happy SQL-ing!

Comment: Kalmino, is there a way to get revenue amounts per each month in each separate column?

Eg; If I choose a 12 month date range, Can I have 12 columns showing revenue for each month from that salesman?
OR if I choose an 8 month date range, can I have 8 columns showing revenue for each month from that salesman?

Comment: Sorry, I had an answer but it wasn't correct.  You can add a SELECT statement to your FROM list that is specifically summing your values by month, then you can join to that "table" (SQL will turn your query into a temp table) and select your values out of it.  It's a little complicated but do a Google search for "Joining on a subquery" and that should help.  I'm a little busy but I'll check in after work to see how it's going :)

Comment: Last thought: if a single query starts getting a little too chaotic, consider making it a stored procedure; especially if you want the date range to be dynamic.  That gives you more time to work with your data instead of trying to gather it, format it and return it all in one statement.  Even if your procedure is a little slow at first, you can always optimize it later.

Comment: Thank you very much Kalmino. I truly appreciate it. I'll try and work on the dynamic date range. If I could upvote your answer, I would for sure.